# AngularJS How to update nested model in select box using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

Trying to update a model in a sibling controller with the selection of a dropdown box.

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    FirstCtrl Person: {{selectedPerson.last}}<br>
    <select 
        ng-options="p.first + ' ' + p.last for p in people"
        ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>

    {{ selectedPerson }}
</fieldset>
<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
SecondCtrl Person: {{selectedPerson.last}}<br>
</div>
```

I tried several solutions (factory, service) and they work quite well with input fields, but not with select boxes.
I made a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwrrr85h/)
How can this be achieved in a simple yet angular way?

Comment: I am not getting what exactly your requirement is

Answer (score 0):

Finally, here a little trick where two controller have no parent/child relationship.
It should pass data from one controller through $rootScope and the $broadcast method.

**app.js**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($rootScope,$scope) {
    $scope.selectedPerson = null;
    $scope.people = [
        { id: 1, first: 'John', last: 'Rambo', actor: 'Silvester' },
        { id: 2, first: 'Rocky', last: 'Balboa', actor: 'Silvester' },
        { id: 3, first: 'John', last: 'Kimble', actor: 'Arnold' },
        { id: 4, first: 'Ben', last: 'Richards', actor: 'Arnold' }
    ];
    $rootScope.updatePerson = function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('update_SecondCtrl', $scope.selectedPerson);
    }
});
myapp.controller('SecondCtrl', function ($rootScope,$scope) {
$scope.selectedPerson = null;
$scope.people = [
    { id: 1, first: 'John', last: 'Rambo', actor: 'Silvester' },
    { id: 2, first: 'Rocky', last: 'Balboa', actor: 'Silvester' },
    { id: 3, first: 'John', last: 'Kimble', actor: 'Arnold' },
    { id: 4, first: 'Ben', last: 'Richards', actor: 'Arnold' }
];

$rootScope.$on("update_SecondCtrl", function(event, selectedPerson) {
    $scope.selectedPerson = selectedPerson;
  });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <select 
        ng-options="p.first + ' ' + p.last for p in people"
        ng-model="selectedPerson"
        ng-change="updatePerson()"
        ></select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    <select
        ng-options="p.first + ' ' + p.last group by p.actor for p in people"
        ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>
    {{ selectedPerson }}
</fieldset>
```

I have update the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwrrr85h/3/).